# Changing default shell

Tags: linux, shell

Sometimes I impress myself with my ability to screw things up: I changed the default shell of root with the chsh command, problem is I forgot to put in the full path. Now I can't log in as root. Is there a file somewhere that I can edit to change roots' default shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's in `/etc/passwd`, but you'll need to be logged in as root to change it.  You've said you can't log in now, but do you still have a live root window from before the change?

Comment: Or you could boot with a live CD/DVD or you could use `sudo vi /etc/passwd` if it is allowed for your non-root user (which hopefully exists). Also `su root -c 'vi /etc/passwd'` should work without a default shell.

Comment: a catch-22 for sure. I don't have sudo set up but I do have separate user. root is logged out. It's a VPS so no CD/DVD available. Guess I'll have to re-install?

Comment: Do your VPS provider offer some kind of rescue system?

Comment: brilliant, the VPS control-panel had a custom java console app which uses its own shell. Was able to change the passwd file as suggested, can now log in as root. Resolved! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

The shell for an user is specified in `/etc/passwd`, it's the last entry in each line; example:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

In this case, the shell is `/bin/bash`.

Of course, you will have to log in as root in order to edit it, which in your case could be... difficult. If you have other user accounts on the system, you can log in as one of them and then use `sudo` to act as root and edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `/etc/passwd` file and change the first line to be like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a VPS, ask the company to shut down the VM and mount your partition from Domain0  and modify yout /etc/passwd file (I guess they are providing VM on Xen).

Comment: That's *quite* a big guess...